# How to show all buffers in vim using powerline?

Tags: vim, powerline

I want to show all buffers' names on statusline(I use powerline). And I hope current buffer can be highlighted, while others are not. When I use **:bn** or **:bp** it highlights the changed buffer. How can I make it?

Comment: There are plugins out there that do this but I don't know how they would be integrated into powerline as I don't know anything about it.  Take a look at buftabs and/or bufstat if you want to take a shot at integrating them.  Disclosure: I wrote bufstat a lifetime ago and I'm not sure I could even tell you how it works now.

Comment: Add `set tabline=2` in your vimrc. It's not the status line, but it will show all your buffers in the tabline.

Comment: I currently have 557 buffers in `:ls!` and 33 in `:ls`. There's simply no way to list that many buffers in a useful fashion in a pseudo tab-line or in the statusline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to do such a thing with powerline, however I have come across [vim-buftabline](https://github.com/ap/vim-buftabline) which does what you ask but with the tabline instead of the statusline.

Personally, I would forget doing this in the statusline or tabline, because it is very easy to run out of space on either line. I would also stop using `:bn`/`:bp` and just use `:b` instead to jump directly to the buffer in question.

Behold the power of `:b`:

- Uses `<tab>` completion
- Use `<c-d>` to list out completion
- Use partial file name. e.g. `:b foo`. Works great with `<tab>`.
- Globbing. e.g. `:b foo*bar` or `:b foo/**/bar`
- Might want to use `'hidden'` via `set hidden`
- Split variant of `:b` is `:sb`.
- Also accepts a buffer number

A common mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :b
:h :ls
:h 'switchbuf'
:h 'hidden'
:h 'tabline'
```

Answer (score 3):

In powerline, the list of open buffers can be displayed by adding the following line to your `.vimrc` configuration file:

```
set showtabline=2
```

This will add an additional status line at the top of your vim session and also highlight the active buffer.

Source: [Powerline documentation](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips-and-tricks.html#useful-settings)